# Subobjects of directed colimits of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, category-theory

Is it true that subobjects of directed colimits of groups are directed colimits of subobjects?

Comment: Do you have a little bit more to say?  What motivates you to ask this?  From where does this question of yours arise?  Provide a bit of context, maybe?  I'm not trying to drill you, but rather encourage you to flesh out your question addressing a question or two that I ask.  It will likely be far better received here.  It helps potential answerers fine tune their answers.

Comment: I understand your point, but this is just a curiosity. Somehow there is no context. Question make perfectly sense in this state. Normally I would provide more context but again, this is not the case. I find the statement reasonable but I expect there is a tricky counterexample. Anyone who is very inside group theory probably will find it very trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In $\mathbf{Grp}$, every monomorphism is regular](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/regular+monomorphism#proposition_3), i.e. an equalizer of some parallel pair. [Directed colimits](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/directed+colimit) are filtered colimits. [Filtered colimits commute with finite limits in $\mathbf{Set}$](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/filtered+limit#commutation_with_small_limits) and categories built on $\mathbf{Set}$ such as categories of models of a [Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory). [$\mathbf{Grp}$ is a category of models (over $\mathbf{Set}$) for a Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory#the_theory_of_groups). Therefore, directed colimits commute with equalizers in $\mathbf{Grp}$.

Comment: I think I love you.

Comment: @Ivan, you should hyperlink your comment too.

Comment: Actually, this argument is subtly incomplete (though fixable). Commutation of limits and colimits can't quite be applied because regularity doesn't quite guarantee enough. We have an equalizer $E\rightarrowtail\mathsf{Colim}_I D\rightrightarrows X$ but to apply commutation we need an equalizer like $E\rightarrowtail\mathsf{Colim}_I D \rightrightarrows\mathsf{Colim}_I D'$. However, $X\cong\mathsf{Colim}_I(\Delta X)$ when $I$ is filtered. (We then need to combine $D$ and $D'$ into one bifunctor but for that we just factor through $\mathsf{Colim}_I D$.)